# Extract exe, dll files from a jpg file

Tags: extract, jpeg, exe

I have several jpg files with video, audio and other exe files embedded in the jpg's. This is not a typical steganography hide as 52k jpg is now 15MB... Tools like pestudio find some of the code but not all. HexBrowser identifed H263 and mp3 formats... It also appears that a setup.exe was embedded but crashes in sandbox. Any ideas on how to sort this out and tools that might help are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a jpg file, even if it does have a jpg extension. Do you know what file type it is? You can use the linux `file` command or something like https://mark0.net/onlinetrid.html

Comment: Some photos open in the jpg viewer which surprised me.I looked for SOI and EOI offsets and could not find them in some.

Comment: TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.24 - (C) 2003-16 By M.Pontello
Definitions found:  13163
Analyzing...
32.2% (.JPG/JPEG) JFIF-EXIF JPEG Bitmap (5000/1/1)  *Files from  -v  option  (12)
 25.8% (.JPG/JPEG) JFIF JPEG bitmap (4003/3)                                                   (76)
 19.3% (.JPG/JPEG) JPEG bitmap (3000/1)                                                          (78)
 16.1% (.MP3) MP3 audio (ID3 v1.x tag) (2500/1/1)                                         (21)
  6.4% (.MP3) MP3 audio (1000/1)                                                                     (34)